# How to fade in/out a UIKit element (UItextField) with cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uitextfield

I have a CCLayer with stuff (sprites, label, etc) on it.
This CCLayer is called normally with a :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[AdventureLayer sceneWithLevel:[itemPassedIn tag]] withColor:ccWHITE]];
```

It comes with some kind of white fading of 1 sec.

However, on this layer, I also have a UITextField added to the CCDirector

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:textField];
```

The problem is : When the layer is showed up, everything goes accordingly with the fading effect EXCEPT the UITextField which is already showed up.

This is too "brutal", and I would like to have some fading effect on it.

How should I proceed ? (I am working with cocos2d v2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an additional animation on the UITextfield. A normal UIView animation which is quite simple. Or maybe find some equivalent for a UITextField in Cocos2d, here is a possible solution from clarus: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/20993

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2010/12/09/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial/) is a tutorial for UIView Animations. 
The code will look something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
uitextField.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: But how to I use animation on the TextField, that's the problem ...
 Also claurus doesn't have the code for a CCTextField unfortunatly :/ What is the cocos2d team waiting to implement such a great thing ? :/